# Update a config value with compile time Dependency Injection in Play Java framework

Tags: java, playframework, guice, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

I have play framework Java App. I am trying to update a config value from application.conf with compile time dependency injection. Basically I want to update value of db.password config in application.conf when application loads.

Any implementation example on how to achieve this ?